# Unable to Update the Data using Inline Editing

Tags: php, inline-editing

I'm working with an application in PHP where I need to update the contents that has been added in the DB, but I was  not able to update the data using inline editing.

Here is my sample code:

**viewpage.php**

```
function saveLesson(id,pid,content)
  {
    alert(document.getElementById('content'+id).value);
    $("#edit"+id).show(); 
    $("#save"+id).hide();
    body=document.getElementById('content'+id).value;      
      $.ajax({ 
       type: "POST",
       url: 'EditPagehtml1.php',           
       data: {id: id,pid : pid, text:body}, 
       success: function(data)
     {           
       window.location.reload(); 
     },
       error: function()
     {
     alert("error"); 
     }
    });
```

**EditPagehtml1.php**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <?php   
     include('../chapter/path.php');
     $phid=$_POST['id']; 
     $pageid=$_POST['pid'];
     $text=$_POST['text'];  
        $dbh  = new PDO($dir) or die("cannot open the database"); 
        $query =  "update PAGE_HTML set `PAGE_ID`='".$pageid."',`CONTENT`='".$text."',`LANGUAGE`='EN' WHERE ID=".$phid; 

            $dbh->exec($query);  
   ?>
</body> 
</html>
```

**Save Button Code:**

```
<td id="savelnum<?php echo $row[0]; ?>" ><a href="#" id='save<?php echo $row[0]; ?>' onclick="saveLesson('<?php echo $row[0]; ?>','<?php echo $row[0]; ?>','<?php echo $row[0]; ?>');">Save</a></td>
```

[image]

Comment: you expect editpage.php working but request EditPagehtml1.php by your ajax.

Comment: code has been updated pls verify. i wrongly mentioned the file name

Comment: Do you get an error message? Alert data in your .success() function. And try to wrap ID in your $query into quotes (`ID`). I assume, your field type in the db is correct (TEXT, CHAR, VARCHAR, ...)

Comment: No error message in alert function..even i wrap id into quotes but values not updated..and all the data types declared in db are correct

Comment: How is the function saveLesson() called? Do you get the correct alert (1st command of that function). If it alerts correctly, I would remove/comment it, so alert function doesn't interact with ajax. If its not alerting correctly, you have to fix the content grabbing (disable the reload temporarily) 

Finallay, clean EditPagehtml1.php and remove every html and just leave php code. If path.php is not needed, delete it. Where comes $dir in the PDO construction?